# Is it possible to create a managed byte array from an IntPtr + size?

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmanaged

I am working with an unmanaged API which exposes a callback function. This function receives an `IntPtr` and an integer which describe a byte array. The API expects me to fill it with data.

I would like to use a managed `byte[]` to fill that buffer. The way I've been doing it so far is something like this:

```
public void MyCallback(IntPtr rawBufferPtr, int rawBufferLength)
{
    var buffer = new byte[rawBufferLength];

    <fill the buffer with whatever data I want>

    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, rawBufferPtr, rawBufferLength);
}
```

Is it possible to avoid the `Marshal.Copy` and somehow allocate the `byte[]` to store the data directly at `rawBufferPtr`?

If not, what other options are there for avoiding the block copy? Is `byte*` essentially the only alternative?

Comment: You'll be explicitly writing unsafe code when you do this.  Might as well make it obvious, use byte*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Marshal.WriteXXX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) family of functions to write directly to the unmanaged buffer.

Example:

```
Marshal.WriteByte(rawBufferPtr, <offset into buffer>, byteValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

`byte *` is essentially the only alternative, if you want to avoid the call to `Marshal.Copy`.  There's no way to tell the runtime to allocate a byte array at a particular unmanaged address.  You'll need to use unsafe code if you want to avoid the copy.